# Writing a VBA Unit Testing Suite

Tags: vba, unit-testing

I am trying to write a addin that will let me write Unit tests for VBA. I Have a class setup for testing assertions etc. what I am missing is a way to stubing/mocking classes is there a way of doing that?

For clarification I am talking about instantiating objects that are pretending to be of a different class. For example, I want to write a mock of Address class that Person class will work with:

Person Class

```
 Private Home as Address

 Sub ChangeAddress(NewStreetAddress as String)
      Address.Street = NewStreetAddress
 end Sub
```

Address Class

```
Dim Street as String
```

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking but it sounds like you might be looking for [Interfaces and Implementation](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Implements.aspx)

Comment: You probably don't need to mock the `Address` class. What you probably need though is a way to specify the instance from the outside. If you're `New`ing up the class inside `Person` you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Testable, object-oriented VBA code that lets you control dependencies, must be written against abstractions. [Extensible logging](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64109/23788) on Code Review Stack Exchange is a good example of that.

In a nutshell, your code needs to depend on *interfaces* - only then can your unit tests pass in "fake" implementations. Take the `ILogger` class module from the linked CR post:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Log(ByVal output As String)
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Property Get MinLevel() As LogLevel
End Property
```

That's the *interface*. One implementation is called `DebugLogger` and goes like this - notice **Implements ILogger**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TDebugLogger
    Name As String
    MinLevel As LogLevel
End Type
Private this As TDebugLogger

Implements ILogger

Public Function Create(ByVal loggerName As String, ByVal loggerMinLevel As LogLevel) As ILogger

    Dim result As New DebugLogger
    result.Name = loggerName
    result.MinLevel = loggerMinLevel
    Set Create = result

End Function

Friend Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Friend Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
    this.Name = value
End Property

Friend Property Get MinLevel() As LogLevel
    MinLevel = this.MinLevel
End Property

Friend Property Let MinLevel(ByVal value As LogLevel)
    this.MinLevel = value
End Property

Private Sub ILogger_Log(ByVal output As String)
    Debug.Print output
End Sub

Private Property Get ILogger_MinLevel() As LogLevel
    ILogger_MinLevel = this.MinLevel
End Property

Private Property Get ILogger_Name() As String
    ILogger_Name = this.Name
End Property
```

---

Now if you have code that uses an `ILogger`, your unit tests can pass in an implementation that, instead of printing stuff to the console, raises an event that reports what message is being logged and at what level: your test module can handle these events, set a module-level flag, and [assuming you have implemented an `Assert` class, or that you are using [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) unit tests] you can then call `Assert.IsTrue` to validate the flag. Or whatever.

Bottom line, it can totally be done: I have an `IRepository` interface with implementations hitting a database, and my unit tests use "fake" implementations that really just wrap a `Collection` instead.

As for *mocking*, as in, *generating an implementation on-the-fly*, and injecting that, ... that's not something easily done, but I can see Rubberduck offering something like it in a future version.

---

> **Disclaimer** - I co-own the Rubberduck project and repository.